# LocalTime(00:01:002) turns to (24:00:02) after saving to ElasticSearch by Spring data elasticsearch repo

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, localtime

when I save the LocalTime object with Spring Data ElasticSearch repository interface, I find the data in ElasticSearch changed unexpectedly,the LocalTime with Value "00:01:01" changed to "24:01:01".

I use Java LocalTime to record the time period in a day , the value need to be save and retrieve from ElasticSearch by Spring Data ElasticSearch interface

```
 @JsonFormat(pattern = "kk:mm:ss", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
 private LocalTime toTime;
```

I expect that the value should nob be changed when I store it in ElasticSearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pattern like `HH:mm:ss` instead of `kk:mm:ss`

Comment: thank you ,Nitin , I tried but failed, the exception is :xception) Text '00:10:01' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=10, MilliOfSecond=0, MicroOfSecond=0, HourOfAmPm=0, SecondOfMinute=1, NanoOfSecond=0},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalTime` from String \"00:10:01\": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalTime

Comment: To be clear , this deserializing happens in the Post of Spring RestController, not in saving it to elasticsearch ,and I find "kk:mm:ss" formate correctly in restcontroller. But when I save it to ES , the hour value of LocalTime (00:10:1) changed to 24.

Comment: HH take 0-23 hour format while kk take 1-24 hour format

Comment: You can use ```java.util.Date``` to parse instead of ```java.time.LocalTime```. It worked well for me.

Comment: that's the last straw I would go and grip ,but for now I want to figure out what the real cause is for the problem.

Comment: I made a mistake , and you are right with formatting string "HH:mm:ss" for the issue,I will mark it as the answer for the question, thanks.